# Error when updating server to 17.04

Tags: server, upgrade, update-manager, 17.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm working on updating a staging server to the latest version of ubuntu. I'm running into an error that I can't figure out...

When I run

`do-release-upgrade -d`

I get the following error

```
ERROR:root:parse failed for ‘/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts-development’
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py”, line 368, in download
    self.parse()
  File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py”, line 239, in parse
    while index_tag.step():
SystemError: E:Unable to parse package file  (1)
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this issue?

Update:

I've discovered that the server is looking for a file called `meta-release-lts-development`, which doesn't exist (only `meta-release-lts`, which has only official releases). Not sure what to do with that information, but might be helpful...

Output of `update-manager -c`

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING:root:can not import unity GI cannot import name Dbusmenu, introspection typelib not found
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: What is the current version? If it is 17.04, it is "the latest".

Comment: @Pilot6 the version we're running now is 16.04.3

Comment: Then run `do-release-upgrade` without  `-d`. If a distro is not found first run `update-manager -c`.

Comment: What does `update-manager -c` do? I can't find documentation on it..

Comment: Where are you looking for "documentation"? Run `man update-manager`.

Comment: Verify at update-manager settings if it is assigned to receive only LTS updates, so it will not find any update to 16.04.

Comment: Hm, `update-manager -c` returns errors - `Failed to connect to Mir` etc. Is there another method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `do-release-upgrade` fails, you might need to edit the `release-updates` file. Open that file with a text editor (e.g. nano)
`nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`
Edit the last line to say:

`Prompt=normal`

Then run `do-release-upgrade` (without the -d flag)

When the upgrade is complete, edit that line again to say
`Prompt=lts`

Comment: Works well. May I know what does this do though?

Comment: @vignesh this has the update-manager look for all new distribution versions instead of only lts (long term support). You can also set this in the GUI through the update-manager.